# Sphinx extension error (sphinxprettysearchresults): for event 'build-finished', error "exception: name 'unicode' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-sphinx

In my Sphinx project (Python 3.12.1, Sphinx 7.2.6 under Windows 10), when trying to generate the output HTML code using the "sphinx-build -E" command, I get the following persistent error:

```
"Extension error (sphinxprettysearchresults):
Handler <function build_search_snippets at 0x0000022451ACBF60> for event 'build-finished' threw an exception (exception: name 'unicode' is not defined)".
```

Earlier in 2023-2024, I resolved a bunch of similar errors.
One of them:

```
"Extension error (sphinxprettysearchresults):
Handler <function add_custom_source_link at 0x000001B2A7D96CA0> for event 'builder-inited' threw an exception (exception: name 'os' is not defined)"
```

I resolved the issue by adding the following three lines of code at the beginning of the file Python\Lib\site-packages\sphinxprettysearchresults_init_.py:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
```

I ENTERED THE FOLLOWING:

```
...\root\myrepo>sphinx-build -E d:\Luxoft\root\myrepo\en ...\root\myrepo-build\output\en
```

I GOT THE FOLLLOWING:

```
Running Sphinx v7.2.6
...\Python\Lib\site-packages\sphinxcontrib\images.py:32: RemovedInSphinx80Warning: The alias     'sphinx.util.status_iterator' is deprecated, use 'sphinx.util.display.status_iterator' instead. Check CHANGES for Sphinx API modifications.
 from sphinx.util import status_iterator
Initiated sphinxcontrib-images backend: `sphinxcontrib_images_lightbox2.lightbox2:LightBox2`
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
writing output...
building [html]: targets for 925 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 925 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] usd_hydra/hydra
Downloading remote images...
Copying static files for sphinxcontrib-images...[100%] lightbox2-customize/jquery-noconflict.js
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
copying assets... copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
done
writing output... [  0%] amd_renderstudio/about
Extension error (sphinxprettysearchresults):
Handler <function build_search_snippets at 0x000001C9701CBF60> for event 'build-finished' threw an exception (exception: name 'unicode' is not defined)
```

Comment: The error indicates that some part of the code was written for Python 2.x and needs to be modified to work with Python 3.x.

Comment: https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/sphinx-pretty-searchresults/issues Hope you can reach out to the author(s) or step up to fix the issues on your own for this project out of maintenance for 6 years.